# Reading integer from arduino using pyserial

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I am sending integer value from arduino and reading it in Python using pyserial 
The arduino code is:

```
Serial.write(integer)
```

And the pyserial is:

```
ser=serial.Serial ('com3',9600,timeout =1)
X=ser.read(1)
print(X)
```

But it doesn't print anything except blank spaces 
Does anyone knows how to read this integer passed from arduino in Python?

Comment: What values does `integer` take? What's its type exactly? Could it be you're passing such bytes that may be interpreted as non-printable ASCII or space?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use a start bit.

The problem might be that the arduino has already written the integer by the time pyserial is running?

So write a character from pyserial to arduino to signal start like

```
    ser=serial.Serial ('com3',9600,timeout =1)
    ser.write(b'S')
    X=ser.read(1)
    print(X)
```

And write the integer from the arduino once you get this start bit.

Answer (score 0):

That is the not the right way to read an `Integer` from Arduino. `Integer` is a 32-bit type while your serial port would be set to **EIGHTBITS** *(Both in pyserial and Arduino. Correct me if I'm wrong)* in byte size, therefore you have to write the `Character` version of the `Integer` from Arduino while transmitting it through a Serial Port because a `Character` takes only **EIGHTBITS** in size which is also the convenient way to do the stuff that you need to, very easily.

Long story short, convert your `Integer` into a `String` or a `Character` Array before transmitting. (Chances are there are inbuilt functions available for the conversion).

On a side note here is the correct python code that you'd prefer to use:

```
ser = serial.Serial(
        port='COM3',
        baudrate=9600,
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
    )
    #RxTx
    ser.isOpen()
while 1:
    out = ''
    while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
        out += ser.read(1)
    if out != '':
        print ">>Received String: %s" % out
```

Comment: No need to even check the setting btw, all the other integer overloads of `HardwareSerial::write()` simply do a C-style cast to `uint8_t`.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I'm not aware about the arduino part, because I had done it in AT Mega AVR and I have no idea what you just said.

Comment: @SiHa Edited, I tried to manually write the code, should have just copied :)

Comment: To clarify the previous comment: https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.h#L129

Comment: @IljaEverilä You meant to say they are automatically converted to utf-8 format?

Comment: No. They're cast to a byte, an unsigned integer that has 8 bits. Obviously that'll throw away a lot of bits, so it can produce surprising results to the unwary (trying to send negative integers or integers > 255).

Comment: @IljaEverilä That is why I've suggested to use a String or a Char Array for storing the conversion as each Character uses 8 bits and transmit them one by one?

Comment: Yes, that's one way to go about it and it's even [promoted in the docs](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Write). One could also just send the individual bytes of an integer in chosen endianness, if the width is known. I added the 1st comment in relation to "Integer is a 32-bit type while your serial port would be set to EIGHTBITS". Even if the serial port would be setup to some other bit width, the library would still truncate.

Answer (score 0):

An easy program which I tested:

**Arduino:**

```
void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int f1=123;
  // print out the value you read:
  Serial.println(f1);
  delay(1000);    
}
```

**Python:**

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.port = 'COM5'

ser.open()
while True:
  h1=ser.readline() 
  if h1:
    g3=int(h1); #if you want to convert to float you can use "float" instead of "int"
    g3=g3+5;
    print(g3)
```